# Calculate for each element SQL

Tags: sql, data-manipulation, postgresql-9.5

I need to perform a calulation on my data set which is simple:

```
refalt
 AA
 AT
 AC
 ...
```

I use this SQL statement to retrieve my information:

```
select 
refalt,
count(*) as Total,
((
select 
count(*)
from ft_variant
where refalt IN ('AC','AT', 'AA')
)::numeric --Number of times that a couple is in
/
(
select count(*) 
from ft_variant
))as Frequency --Divided by total umber of elements
from ft_variant
group by refalt;
```

My result is quite good except one thing:

```
   Refalt       Total   Frequency
    AC          131682  0.12
    AT          149385  0.12
    AA          55841   0.12
```

The frequency is referring only to AA, i want to calculate the freq for each couple.

The reult should be:

```
   Refalt       Total   Frequency
    AC          131682  0.20
    AT          149385  0.68
    AA          55841   0.12
```

Something's not ok i cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things:

```
select refalt, 
       count(*) as total, 
       count(*)::numeric / (select count(*) from ft_variant) as frequency
from ft_variant
group by refalt
```

If you want to limit that to just `'AC','AT', 'AA'` you can add that in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the percentage of 'AC' + 'AT' + 'AA' in the table. You want to count the percentage of the one refalt you are showing instead.

Probably:

```
select 
  refalt,
  count(*) as total,
  count(*)::numeric / sum(count(*)) over () as frequency
from ft_variant
where refalt in ('AC', 'AT', 'AA')
group by refalt;
```

This only looks at 'AC', 'AT', and 'AA' records and gives you the count per refalt and its percentage within this set.